# How to fix zsh: corrupt history file /home/mis/.zsh_history (Linux)

Tags: zsh

Whenever I open terminal I got his Warning!

`[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected`

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.

You can:

Recommended: Change ~/.zshrc so that it does not perform console I/O
after the instant prompt preamble. See the link below for details.

```
 You will not see this error message again.
 Zsh will start quickly and prompt will update smoothly.
```

Suppress this warning either by running p10k configure or by manually
defining the following parameter:

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet

You will not see this error message again.
Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.
```

Disable instant prompt either by running p10k configure or by manually
defining the following parameter:

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off

* You will not see this error message again.
* Zsh will start slowly.
```

- Do nothing.

  You will see this error message every time you start zsh.
  Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

`console output produced during zsh initialization follows`

`zsh: corrupt history file /home/mis/.zsh_history`

Comment: What happens if you remove your ~/.zsh_history?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve it by removing the package (purge) and reinstall it back. (That is what worked for me.)